# can website use https and static files on http sub-domain

Tags: php, http, ssl, https, subdomain

I want buy ssl license and i have two option. One option support unlimited subdomain ( Wildcard ) and another, not support it. but it's cheaper than Wildcard ssl .

Can my website programming with php and use https protocol and static files like images , css , js , videos on another sub-domain use http protocol ?

Do you think i trouble if do this ?

Comment: Including HTTP resources on a HTTPS page will result in errors and the resources not being loaded. See [Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content). Either put them on the HTTPS domain, or use a free `Let's Encrypt` certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a good idea to use [Mixed Content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) (resources on http, main site on https), and it will be automatically blocked in most browsers, making your page look weird and reduces security.

You have a few choices as I see it, starting from best+cheapest:

1. Use a service such as [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get a free certificate for your subdomain, and use the non-wildcard provider on your main site. Or if you don't need an EV certificate (green company-name), you could just get a LetsEncrypt cert for your main domain as well. You will save money, and it's all secure.
2. Buy the non-wildcard cert and have all static content on your same domain.

For both 1 and 2, I would suggest that you support [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) -- the main reason why people started with using different subdomains for static content is to workaround the connection limiting of HTTP/1.x. With HTTP/2, all content is multiplexed, so there not always a true need for this behavior anymore. In fact, [domain sharding](https://www.nginx.com/blog/7-tips-for-faster-http2-performance/#tip4optimizations/) might make the performance worse.